# jQuery FancyBox 2.0: helpers issues (buttons and thumbs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, fancybox, helper

Despite having followed exactly the guide of the new version 2 of fancybox, I wasn't able to activate helpers. I don't understand where I went wrong.

There is my current code:

HTML:

```
<div id="disegni" style="display: none">
   <div class="title">Disegni</div>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" title="Scultura 1 disegni" href="images/intro/01.jpg"><img src="images/intro/01small.jpg" alt=""/></a>
   <a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" title="Scultura 2 disegni" href="images/intro/02.jpg"><img src="images/intro/02small.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
   openEffect   : 'elastic',
   closeEffect  : 'fade',
   revealEffect: 'none',
   hideEffect   : 'none',
   prevEasing  : 'swing',
   nextEasing  : 'swing',
   helpers  : { 
  title : { 
         type : 'inside' //inside/outside
      }, 
      buttons   : {}
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include js and css files:

```
<!-- Add fancyBox - button helper -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
```

And it should work. Not sure why you added links inside hidden element, but maybe you have to.

Comment: thanks a lot! I had forgotten to import the js and css :) now it works!

Comment: Hi @Androidiam.  Why didn't you check this question as answered ?

Comment: @Janis, How could you possibly know, from the question, that was what was missing?!

Comment: @AlexisWilke Because that is usual issue people are having. Btw, I suggest trying the latest version of fancyBox, it provides toolbar and thumbs out of the box